Uploading to Azure Blob Storage from AppService (Spring Boot) leads to Netty Out of Memory?
I use SpringBoot 3.3.4 with Kotlin and the current azure starter storage implementation("com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-storage-blob:5.17.1")
I get the following exception when uploading blobs above around 20MB to azure blob storage:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot reserve 4390 bytes of direct buffer memory (allocated: 10481572, limit: 10485760)
at java.base/java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Unknown Source)
at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledDirectByteBuf.allocateDirect(UnpooledDirectByteBuf.java:104)
at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledDirectByteBuf.<init>(UnpooledDirectByteBuf.java:64)
at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.<init>(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:41)
at io.netty.buffer.UnsafeByteBufUtil.newUnsafeDirectByteBuf(UnsafeByteBufUtil.java:687)
at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:406)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:188)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:179)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.newDirectBuffer0(AbstractEpollChannel.java:329)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.newDirectBuffer(AbstractEpollChannel.java:320)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.newDirectBuffer(AbstractEpollChannel.java:298)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel.filterOutboundMessage(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:523)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(AbstractChannel.java:866)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1314)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:889)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:875)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:984)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:868)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:885)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapAndFlush(SslHandler.java:820)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.flush(SslHandler.java:801)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:941)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:921)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:907)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:531)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:125)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:356)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:937)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:921)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:907)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:531)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:125)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:356)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:937)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:921)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:907)
at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner.run(MonoSendMany.java:325)
at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner.trySchedule(MonoSendMany.java:434)
at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner.onNext(MonoSendMany.java:223)
at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.reactor.v3_1.TracingSubscriber.onNext(TracingSubscriber.java:68)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.reactor.v3_1.TracingSubscriber.onNext(TracingSubscriber.java:68)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.reactor.v3_1.TracingSubscriber.onNext(TracingSubscriber.java:68)
at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.reactor.v3_1.TracingSubscriber.onNext(TracingSubscriber.java:68)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:129)
at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.reactor.v3_1.TracingSubscriber.onNext(TracingSubscriber.java:68)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatArray.java:180)
at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.reactor.v3_1.TracingSubscriber.onNext(TracingSubscriber.java:68)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:335)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:294)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.request(FluxConcatArray.java:256)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.request(FluxHandle.java:272)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)
at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner.onSubscribe(MonoSendMany.java:254)
at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.reactor.v3_1.TracingSubscriber.onSubscribe(TracingSubscriber.java:61)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92)
at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.reactor.v3_1.TracingSubscriber.onSubscribe(TracingSubscriber.java:61)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92)
at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.reactor.v3_1.TracingSubscriber.onSubscribe(TracingSubscriber.java:61)
at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.reactor.v3_1.TracingSubscriber.onSubscribe(TracingSubscriber.java:61)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxHandle.java:90)
at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.reactor.v3_1.TracingSubscriber.onSubscribe(TracingSubscriber.java:61)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:166)
at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.reactor.v3_1.TracingSubscriber.onSubscribe(TracingSubscriber.java:61)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83)
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8848)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:238)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray.subscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:79)
at reactor.core.publisher.InternalFluxOperator.subscribe(InternalFluxOperator.java:68)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:54)
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8848)
at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany.subscribe(MonoSendMany.java:102)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:241)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:204)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
at reactor.netty.FutureMono.doSubscribe(FutureMono.java:122)
at reactor.netty.FutureMono$DeferredFutureMono.subscribe(FutureMono.java:114)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4576)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:265)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4576)
at reactor.netty.NettyOutbound.subscribe(NettyOutbound.java:336)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSource.subscribe(MonoSource.java:68)
at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)
at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:445)
at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:715)
at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onStateChange(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:205)
at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onStateChange(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:466)
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelActive(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:62)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:260)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:238)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:412)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelActive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:69)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelActive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:211)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:260)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:238)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:412)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelActive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:69)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelActive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:211)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:260)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:238)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
at reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$SslReadHandler.userEventTriggered(SslProvider.java:861)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:398)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:376)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:368)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.userEventTriggered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:117)
at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.netty.v4.common.internal.client.NettySslInstrumentationHandler.userEventTriggered(NettySslInstrumentationHandler.java:122)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:398)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:376)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:368)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeSuccess(SslHandler.java:1960)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:997)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1531)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1358)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1407)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:530)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:469)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1357)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:868)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:799)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe$1.run(AbstractEpollChannel.java:425)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:405)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

The weird thing is when I run my Spring App locally I tested successful uploads to azure blob with 500MB or larger.
When deployed on an Azure AppService (Linux, Container) I see timeouts and the mentioned netty exceptions.
I build my image with the gradle bootBuildImage target without further configuration. I am not sure to which component this is related to:

My Implementation
Azure AppService
Gradle Docker Build (Memory Settings?)
...

Initially I just used uploadBlob(inputStream), however I switched looking for a solution.
val blobClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName).getBlobClient(blobPath)
        if (blobClient.exists()) throw AzureStorageBlobAlreadyExistsException(blobPathPrefix)

        try {
            val blobParallelUploadOptions = BlobParallelUploadOptions(file.inputStream)
                .setParallelTransferOptions(
                    ParallelTransferOptions()
                        .setBlockSizeLong(4*1024*1024)
                        .setMaxSingleUploadSizeLong(4*1024*1024)
                        .setMaxConcurrency(2)
                )

            blobClient.uploadWithResponse(blobParallelUploadOptions, null, null)
            blobClient.setHttpHeaders(BlobHttpHeaders().apply { contentDisposition = "attachment; filename=$fileName" })
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logger.error("Error when uploading file ($fileName) to Azure Storage on container $containerName to $blobPath")
            throw AzureStorageGeneralUploadException().apply { initCause(e) }
        }


Refer this https://medium.com/@stackbender/boosting-performance-with-azure-blob-storage-in-java-d9e6778a81be for uploading large files.

The solution in my case was simple. Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=200M resolved the issue. Default with the buildpacks was 10M, which was not sufficient.
